# He shall die. He will die

Tags: grammar, will-shall

1. He shall die.
2. He *will* die. (Will is stressed.)
3. He will die. (Will is not stressed.)

What is the difference among them?

Number 1 means that I will kill him.

Number 2 means that he intends to die.

Number 3 is a simple future. He will die as time passes.

Is my explanation plausible?

Comment: The difference between "shall" and "will" is rather subtle and merits its own Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will.

Comment: Nowhere in *he shall die* does it imply *I will kill him*. That's a completely false assumption. (Not only that he will be killed but that *you* will kill him.)